# O(1) minimum in a changing fixed size array

Tags: algorithm, math

I have an array with 32 numbers. Initially, every number is 0, although it's probably not important.

At any time I can change one number in this array.

I want to quickly find the minimum value and its index after such an update. Is there a way to do it in O(1) time?

Comment: You can log what you want simultaneously when you change the numbers in the array?

Comment: almost everything you do on an array of size 32 is `O(1)`. Linear scan requires 32 comparisons, which is in `O(1)`

Comment: @amit The size of the array does not matter in deciding if the algorithm is O(1) or not. Linear scan on an array with 32 values is not O(1).

Comment: @user16367: It is. O(1) = constant number of ops. If the array is of size 32 (or any fixed size for the matter), the number of ops is indeed constant (Think of it this way: you can replace the linear scan with a chained if conditions instead of a loop: `if (arr[0] < min), if (arr[1] < min) , ... if (arr[31] < min)`

Comment: A min-heap comes to mind, but for an array with such a tiny constant size I would bet that you are probably better off with a naive linear scan since the constant is smaller and the compiler will probably optimize it into e.g. a jump table. It also depends a bit on which (if any) of the operations is more frequent: modification or finding the minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

almost everything you do on an array of size 32 is `O(1)`. Linear scan requires 32 comparisons, which is in `O(1)`

O(1) = constant number of ops. If the array is of size 32 (or any fixed size for the matter), the number of ops is indeed constant (Think of it this way: you can replace the linear scan with a chained if conditions instead of a loop: 

`if (arr[0] < min), if (arr[1] < min) , ... if (arr[31] < min)`

For the thrill of it, regarding the general case for an array of size `n`, it is not possible with compare based algorithms.

If it was, we could sort in `O(n)` using comparisons based algorithm:

```
given an array A:
max <- max(A)
build an empty data structure as desired let it be `S`.
for each element of A - insert it into S in a different index.
while (S.min() <= max):
   idx <- S.findminIndex()
   print S.min()
   S.update(idx,max+1)
```

Assuming each op in the above algorithm is `O(1)`, and the loop iterates `n` times, your algorithm sorts A in `O(n)` - which cannot be done, since comparations based sorting are proved to be `Omega(nlogn)` problem

Comment: Sadly, I think this makes sense, that it's impossible to do.

Comment: I would disagree with your terminology but I see your point. The big Oh notation is about considering how running time/space changes with the problem size. In this case for an array of size n a linear scan requires O(n) operations. For a given n it would be constant as you have pointed out.

Comment: last upvoter (and @user16367): It was my 1000th upvote on algorithms. I am expected to get the algorithms golden badge thanks to it tomorrow, and be the 2nd ever SO user to earn it. thanks! :)

Comment: I'll reword my previous comment to fit the question: for everything you can do on a fixed-length array of fixed-size numbers that takes no other input, if it finishes, it's O(1). I think it's correct like that, or did I miss anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer an O(1) algorithm, may be one good way is using min heap, to do your updates in `O(log n)` and do find minimum in `O(1)`. min heap for small size array is fast enough and you performance in update is negligible.

Comment: Yes, this would be my last resort.

Comment: And I doubt that if you could find better option when there is no restriction in your inputs, also take care `log n` is too small and is better than too many of linear algorithms with large constant factor.